# Google App Engine Datastore uploading image very slow,taking too much time

Tags: image, performance, google-app-engine, blob, google-cloud-datastore

I am uploading a bitmap image in form of blob data to datastore via endpoints classes.The upload is taking too much time. is there some way i can improve performance.Are there different 'tires' with different ram and clock speed to choose from as it is in cloud SQL?

Comment: It looks like you don't know where the bottleneck is. You should probably start by finding it. App Engine console gives you a lot of information.

Comment: In the appengine settings page, I can see a "Frontend instance class" field,which has got 4 types. I am not sure what it dose,cant see any significant improvement in performance by changing it.

Comment: what is the speed of your connection? Is it across a mobile network?

Comment: Its 2 mbps wifi connection(not shared with anyone).The size of the image is 213783 bytes which would be around 213 kb.And time taken to upload and save is more than 3 minutes.Is this the normal speed of the GAE?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [App Engine Dashboard](https://console.developers.google.com/project). It offers information on CPU utilization, memory usage and latency. Run a few tests and see how they affect the stats. Then, look at the logs. See cpu ms versus total ms.

These are good places to start investigating the problem. Once you know what constrains your app performance, you can start looking for a solution.